# passing data from Wpf program to python script on local machine within an iterative process

Tags: c#, python, wpf, ipc

I am curious as to the best way to share data from a WPF program with a python script from within a loop where the values are continuously being updated.
Here is a psuedo-codish example that expresses the kind of functionality I'm hoping for.

## Wpf example:

```
    while(true)
{
var x = arbitraryNumber0;
var y = arbitraryNumber1;
var z = arbitraryNumber2;

sendToPython(arbitraryNumber0, arbitraryNumber1, arbitraryNumber2);

arbitraryNumber0++;
arbitraryNumber1++;
arbitraryNumber2++;
}
```

## Python script example:

```
  #stream in x, y, z From WPF 
  product = arbNumFromWPF0 * arbNumFromWPF1 * arbNumFromWPF2
  #do stuff with product
```

I have tried using c# process's but the problem was that it would need to start the python shell on every new iteration. Which would cause my system to crash.
I have looked into ironpython, pipes, and sockets but can not find an example similar to what I'm trying to do, and am wondering what method I should use to achieve this functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why cant you use websocket or similar thing?  You can check this question's program for inspiration.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680413/connecting-python-socketserver-with-c-sharp-client

Comment: Why throw regular Python into this Mix? I would stick with IronPython - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app

Comment: I see that IronPython seems to allow for the writing of python inside of .net, and that it can execute python scripts, I just can't find an example that seems to show how to update parameters as they are being read by a separate python script and that could keep reading those updated values on each new iteration. Would I have to execute the script every iteration? I've been having a hard time finding a good resource I could use to figure out IronPython's functionality.

Comment: Please consider providing a concrete example, not pseudo-code.