# Can not connect thrift c# client to python server

Tags: c#, python, c++, sockets, thrift

I have Thrift client-server application C# client and Python server. All in the same machine-Windows7. Debugging into the Thrift code I saw the client's socket cannot connect to the server's local server. 
BTW, The same C# client connects to C+ server and python and c++ clients connect to the same python server. Just C#-->Python combination fails.

The problem looks similar to [Connecting Python SocketServer with C# Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680413/connecting-python-socketserver-with-c-sharp-client). I tried to modify the code following the answer in the link above but still, C# socket throws "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9091"

*Client(C#):*

```
   IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
   IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
   IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
   Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream, 
   ProtocolType.Tcp);
   TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
   tcpClient.Client = client;
   tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);
```

Why `ipHostInfo.AddressList[1]`? This selection takes IPv4 adapter from 
   ipconfig. I tries other indices as well. 
 *Server(Python, Inside 
   to Thrift-sever library):*

```
res0 = socket.getaddrinfo(self.host,
                                          self.port,
                                          self._socket_family,
                                          socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                                          0,
                                          socket.AI_PASSIVE | 
    socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG)
    ...
    self.handle = socket.socket(res[0], res[1])
    self.handle.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    if hasattr(self.handle, 'settimeout'):
     self.handle.settimeout(None)
    self.handle.bind(res[4])
    self.handle.listen(self._backlog)
    client, addr = self.handle.accept()
```

It never exits from `accept` in case of C# client

Comment: Why are you using AddressList[1] and not zero?  When you are on the same machine always make sure your server is listening on IP.Any and the client connects to the machine name (or IP). The refused 127.0.0.1 (loopback address) can occur for a number of different reasons.In general you get it when the client connection does not complete.The machine has a host file (in the c:\windows folder) that can be configured differently so where code will work on some machines on other the hosts file is different and can fail.The Net library gives the refuse error when a client tries to connect to loopback

Comment: @jdweng I tried with the same result. AddressList[0] return IPv6 address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much duplicate code.  Try following :

```
            //client
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(remoteEP);

            //Server
            IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localEP);
            listener.Start();
```

Comment: Conclusion, In case of C# thrift client, socket should be initialized only outside of Thrift client. Thankfully, Thrift client interface enables that.

Comment: the same client code stopped to work. Again, just client C# --> server Python is not working. Looks like the something is missing during initialization. Is there a way to diagnose it?

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the TCP messages.  Pythone if you are getting an exception you can add break points and look at the python object.  I've found useful info in the python object to help debug issues.  For example I found out that my path lengths for files were very large and when I move code from a network drive to c:\ the  code worked.  You can also add into the python log files debug (net4log) messages to help determine issues or look at the existing log files.

Comment: Just run Wireshark with filter "loop and tcp.port == 9091"  on working case (C## --> C++) . I expect to see the capture cause it works. Nothing... Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't know if the Thrift is using more than one port.   A lot of protocols use multiple ports.  The initial port is a command port and additional ports are then used to transfer data.  It is considered more secure to transfer data on a different port than the command channel.  See following : https://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Comment: In in my case. I debug all user space code in all languages include thrift libraries and know which port is used. I thought maybe "loop and tcp.port == 9091" is wrong expression.

Comment: There must be a port 9091 listening since you are not getting a connection error.  You can get a list of all open ports from cmd.exe >Netstat -a  The Transport Network Layer is TCP.

Comment: @jdwend I see listening ports. It's there... Again, The same python server gets all connections well from Python and C++ clients

Comment: What is difference between c# and python?  Are any messages being sent?  does c# connect?

Comment: What do you mean "difference between c# and python"?   C# connects to C++ server

Comment: Ten working and non working.  The title of posting is Python.  So right now I'm not sure how python gets involved.  Nor where the issue is occurring.

Comment: The problem with a code above was that  ```Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());``` returned list of host IP addresses while python server were listening to "localhost". Instead, ```IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");``` solved the problem of loopback connection.

Comment: I said the client and server cannot be using to same IP. It is better to use IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port) for server. Will work under any condition.  The loopback sometimes is use by client while IP.Any is reserved on a windows machine for the Server.  Loopback was designed so you can test a connection from a remote machine (using ping).