# C# communication with Python - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, c#, sockets

I'm trying to set up communication through a TCP/IP connection and are having problems with connecting the C# client to the Python Server.
It throws a `SocketException`:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I'm pretty sure that it is happening at the line where it tries to connect to the Python server: `sender.Connect(remoteEP);`

### What I've tried

- Before I used the IPv4 protocol and Pythons `socket.AF_INET` but I discovered that it seems like that my parsing of the IP Address in C# makes it an IPv6 address so that's what I'm using now but that didn't resolve the problem.
- I also tried using `IPAddress.Parse(ip)` instead of getting the host first with `Dns.GetHostEntry(ip)` but that didn't seem to do anything.

### The code

The C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;


public class PyCommunicator : MonoBehaviour {

    private string ip = "::1"; // Localhost
    private int port = 14654;
    public string dataStringToSend
    {
        get { return dataStringToSend; }
        set { dataStringToSend = value; }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RequestServerCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator RequestServerCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RequestServer();
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10);
        }
    }

    public void RequestServer()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; // 1 KiloByte
        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server,
            // and get host IP Address that is used to establish a connection.
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IPv6 : ::1 
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses  
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.    
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.    
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint  
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Debug.Log("Successfully established a connection between Unity and Python.");

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                dataStringToSend = "Test from C#";
                if (dataStringToSend != "")
                {
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataStringToSend);
                    // Send the data through the socket.
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
                    // Reset.
                    dataStringToSend = "";
                }

                // Receive the response from the remote device.    
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Debug.LogFormat("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.    
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("ArgumentNullException: {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("SocketException: {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Unexpected exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Exception from setup: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code was taken from [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/) link from the client section and modified for my own use.

Python code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep


class Communicator():

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

        self.data_to_send = None
        self.socket = None
        self.socket_conn = None
        self.socket_addr = None

        # Start listening right away.
        self.start()

    
    def start(self):
        """Start listening and accept connection."""
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6,  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))

        # Begin listening for 1 connection.
        self.socket.listen(1)
        print("Socket is listening on ip (" + str(self.ip) + ") and port " + str(self.port))
        self.socket_conn, self.socket_addr = self.socket.accept()
        print("Connection between Unity and Python established. Unity-C# is at: " + str(self.socket_addr))
        
        sleep(5) # TESTING PURPOSES

        # Receive.
        result = ""
        chunk_counter = 0
        while True:
            # Allow the server to read up to 1024 bytes.
            data = self.conn.recv(1024)
            chunk_counter += 1
            # To minimize lag, read guess in chunks.
            if chunk_counter < 5:
                result += data.decode()
            
            # If reading the guess is done,
            # break out of loop.
            if not data:
                break
        
        # Send.
        self.socket.send("Test from python".encode())

        # Close
        self.socket.close()


    def send_data(self):
        """Send data"""
        pass


    def receive_data(self):
        """Receive data"""
        pass


Communicator('::1', 14654)
```

Comment: probably not the real problem, but try it disabling firewalls, this makes me crazy sometimes with tcp connection with unity ^^'

Comment: @Lotan, No sorry, still same problem - but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I didn't search the StackOverflow forum enough.
I found a solution in the code and answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680413/connecting-python-socketserver-with-c-sharp-client) StackOverflow answer.

I didn't need to use the actual `localhost` loopback address and instead needed to get the `HOSTNAME` address through C#'s DNS function:

```
Dns.GetHostName()
```

I also used `socket.gethostname()` in Python so that they would have same addresses when connecting.

I also changed the whole thing to use IPv4 addresses and found out in the answer of the linked question that the first element in `host.AddressList` contains IPv6 addresses while the second AND last element contained IPv4 addresses, and that was the missing piece.

### UPDATED CODE

C# Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;


public class PyCommunicator : MonoBehaviour {

    private int port = 14654;
    public string dataStringToSend
    {                                                                               
        get { return dataStringToSend; }
        set { dataStringToSend = value; }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RequestServerCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator RequestServerCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RequestServer();
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10);
        }
    }

    public void RequestServer()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; // 1 KiloByte
        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server,
            // and get host IP Address that is used to establish a connection.
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IP : 127.0.0.1
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses  
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.    
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.    
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint  
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Debug.Log("Successfully established a connection between Unity and Python.");

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                dataStringToSend = "Test from C#";
                if (dataStringToSend != "")
                {
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataStringToSend);
                    // Send the data through the socket.
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
                    // Reset.
                    dataStringToSend = "";
                }

                // Receive the response from the remote device.    
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Debug.LogFormat("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.    
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("ArgumentNullException: {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("SocketException: {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Unexpected exception: {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Exception from setup: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep


class Communicator():

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

        self.data_to_send = None
        self.socket = None
        self.socket_conn = None
        self.socket_addr = None

        # Start listening right away.
        self.start()

    
    def start(self):
        """Start listening and accept connection."""
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))

        # Begin listening for 1 connection.
        self.socket.listen(1)
        print("Socket is listening on ip (" + str(self.ip) + ") and port " + str(self.port))
        self.socket_conn, self.socket_addr = self.socket.accept()
        print("Connection between Unity and Python established. Unity-C# is at: " + str(self.socket_addr))
        
        sleep(5) # TESTING PURPOSES

        # Receive.
        result = ""
        chunk_counter = 0
        while True:
            # Allow the server to read up to 1024 bytes.
            data = self.conn.recv(1024)
            chunk_counter += 1
            # To minimize lag, read guess in chunks.
            if chunk_counter < 5:
                result += data.decode()
            
            # If reading the guess is done,
            # break out of loop.
            if not data:
                break
        
        # Send.
        self.socket.send("Test from python".encode())

        # Close
        self.socket.close()


    def send_data(self):
        """Send data"""
        pass


    def receive_data(self):
        """Receive data"""
        pass


Communicator(socket.gethostname(), 14654)
```

Comment: Tried out the code, and it seems there is a recursion problem in your C# script. The `dataStringToSend` variable is calling on itself. Did you not get that problem?

Comment: @Daniel Zaksevski Can you point out to me in the code where exactly you're referring to? If you mean the getters and setters, there's nothing wrong with that. The getter returns the variable, and the setter sets variable with the value written on the right side.